# aclaracion en rutas nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, router

necesito que me aclaren una duda, ya he investigado en varios lugares y no comprendo todavia, es en cuanto a las rutas en node js, quiero entender el siguiente trozo de codigo:

```
// Routes
app.use(require('./routes/'));
app.use(require('./routes/authentication'));
app.use('/links', require('./routes/links'));
```

Osea entiendo que en la primera requerimos el index de la carpeta de las rutas, y que en el segundo requerimos el archivo que contiene las rutas de autentificacion, osea el registro y el login, y en el tercero requerimos las rutas de la app principal(es una app de links, por eso se llama asi :D), ahora, lo que no entiendo es porque en el tercero es necesario no solo poner el require, sino especificar el 'links', osea, no entiendo porque debe de ser asi, y no puede ser como las anteriores que simplemente tienen el requiere.

Por favor si alguien me puede aclarar esta duda sería genial :D, feliz resto de día programadores :D

Comment: Podrias mostrar un estracto de los archivos a los cuales estas llamando ?

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo es asignar una ruta a las posibles rutas que tenga el archivo, es decir que cada ruta que tenga dentro de ese archivo, quedara como '/links/[ruta]' ([express](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#app.use))

Comment: @ignacionicolasdonosofiguero pero porqué en los demas no es necesario?, o más bien replanteo la pregunta... cual es la diferencia entre poner app.use('/links', require('./routes/links'));  a poner app.use(require('./routes/links'));  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es para que las rutas que estén en el archivo `routes/links` tengan como prefijo `"/links".

Por ejemplo si el archivo tiene una ruta `/hola` será accesible vía `https://mi-sttio.com/links/hola`

Comment: efectivamente, eso me fije despues de mirar y mirar, igualmente, mil y mil gracias :D